# Calculating position of a target based on XY coordinates of an image and viceversa

Tags: math, trigonometry, angle

I have a camera mounted on a boat. Knowing that my reference point will always be the sea (the target i need to aim are boats) and a few other parameters like camera height above the sea, fov (and eventually also pitch and roll, but if it's too complicated i'll presume both are 0 for now). Picking XY points in the image of the camera, i want to get distance and bearing of that point.
And viceversa, having distance and bearing of a point, i want to get its XY coordinates of the camera image.

Note that i need a formula that's as much accurate as possible, taking into consideration also earth's curvature.

I need to do this in javascript, but every programming language is good, i just need to understand the math.

I have no idea how to achieve this